# 1 of 2 update panels not updating (same code) and string not getting set

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I was trying to set a public string in my codebehind onclick of a button, then later run a function against the new value, but the value isnt getting set. Also my updatepanel "upTables" isnt working, it refershes the page, however my update panel "upForm" works and doesnt refresh the page, ive setup both panels the same way too, please see my code below

ive trimmed it down for readbility,

basically when i click butusers, strmode is not getting set to Users and the whole page refreshes, this does not happen when i click butEdit...

Thanks

form.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="cntMenu" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuContent" runat="Server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smEquipment" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-title">Equpiment</li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="butUsers" runat="server" OnClick="butUsers_Click">User Workstations</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="cntCenter" ContentPlaceHolderID="CenterContent" runat="Server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTables" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <table id="table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>AssetNo</th>
                <th>CPU</th>
                <th>Asset Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="butEdit" runat="server" OnClick="butEdit_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td><%# Eval("AssetNo") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("CPU") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("AssetType") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cntRight" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upForm" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="details">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidID" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUserID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                <table class="detailsview" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td_title_align">Asset No:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssetNo" runat="server" CssClass="edit_box"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="td_title_align">CPU:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCPU" runat="server" CssClass="edit_box"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="td_title_align">Asset Type:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAssetType" runat="server" CssClass="edit_box"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

form.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class equipment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable dtEquipment;
    dsDataTableAdapters.tblEquipmentTableAdapter taEquipment;
    dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable dtEdit;
    public string strMode { get; set; }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strMode = "Default";
        dtEquipment = new dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable();
        dtEdit = new dsData.tblEquipmentDataTable();
        taEquipment = new dsDataTableAdapters.tblEquipmentTableAdapter();
    }
    protected void butUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        butUsers.CssClass = "highlight";
        strMode = "Users";
        taEquipment.FillbyUser(dtEquipment);
        rptItems.DataSource = dtEquipment;
        rptItems.DataBind();
        upTables.Update();
    }
    protected void butEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddAssetType.Items.Clear();
        switch (strMode)
        {
            case "Users":
                ddAssetType.Items.Add("Laptop");
                ddAssetType.Items.Add("Workstation");
            break;
        }

        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        int intID = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);

        taEquipment.FillByRecordID(dtEdit, intID);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtEdit.Rows)
        {

            //Populate Fields
            hidUserID.Value = dr["UserID"].ToString();
            hidID.Value = dr["ID"].ToString();
            txtAssetNo.Text = dr["AssetNo"].ToString();
            txtCPU.Text = dr["CPU"].ToString();

            ddAssetType.SelectedValue = dr["AssetType"].ToString();

            upForm.Update();
        }

    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it!

```
        smEquipment.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(butUsers);
```